# Selenium NoSuchElementException while trying to find an element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue with Selenium targeting a username and password textbox. My main goal is to have my program open Chrome browser, load isis.ufl.edu, proceed to registration, then sign on with the user's username and password. The problem is that when I give an xpath or css path to target the username and password textbox, Eclipse gives me a error stating it cant find the element. Some say this only occurs with Chrome but does anyone know a way around this?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such       element
  (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457    (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.2 x86_64)  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'Dailens-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.102', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.2', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: c8b9c346dcf7bcdc28c1cc078638d872
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/81/v5g4vbfj05x16pgjg9h7_kf40000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.ML2rMj}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=40.0.2214.115, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:441)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:426)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:51)
```

Here is my code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class TestClass  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Fetching isis and schedule information
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("User enter Isis username:");
    System.out.println("User enter Isis password:");
    System.out.println("User enter current semester:");
    String username = user_input.next();
    String password = user_input.next();
    String semester = user_input.next();

    // Create a new instance of the chrome driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
    // not the implementation.
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//users/dailenspencer/downloads/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


    // And now use this to visit isis
    driver.get("http://www.isis.ufl.edu/");
    // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
    // driver.navigate().to("http://www.isis.ufl.edu/");

    //Clicking on registration tab
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='hideToggle2']")).click();


    //If user input fall for semester, click on fall registration
   if(semester.charAt(0) == 'f' || semester.charAt(0) == 'F'){
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#reg > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(3) > a")).click();

   }

   //If user input summer, click on summer registration tab
   if(semester.charAt(1) == 'u'){
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#reg > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(2) > a")).click();
   }

   //else, click spring registration tab
   else{
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#reg > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(1) > a")).click();
   }

   long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
   while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
       WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("wrap"));

       // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
       if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
         break;
       }
   }



   //Find the textbox for username, and send username to text box
   WebElement elementu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#username"));
   elementu.sendKeys(username);

   WebElement elementp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#password"));
   elementp.sendKeys(password);







    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.content > div > form > p:nth-child(3) > input")).click();



    // Check the title of the page
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

    // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
    // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("isis");
        }
    });



    //Close the browser
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *explicitly wait for elements to become visible* before interacting with them, example for the "Transcripts" link:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='hideToggle2']")));
```

Also, it looks like it is failing while trying to find the Summer registration link. I'd find it *by partial link text* instead of diving into CSS selectors:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Summer")).click();
```